# How to output graphics while maintaining alphabetical order

Tags: r, ubuntu

I have a script to output graphic files via png()

the filename is based on a value(p) and the observation id ID(numerical value).

```
> summary(p)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
0.05328 0.10770 0.20830 0.31140 0.42360 0.99990 
> summary(id)
     Min.   1st Qu.    Median      Mean   3rd Qu.      Max. 
100000000 114100000 130400000 186100000 287300000 4513000
> str(p)
 num [1:223] 0.175 0.1499 0.156 0.0636 0.1628 ...
> str(id)
 int [1:223] 100037005 100270001 100270002 100801001 101910002 101910003 101910007 102510001 103630003 103630005 ...
```

so that

> `png(paste(p," - ", id,".png)`

My goal is that the files in the output directory, when sorted by name, are in increasing p order, while the id is still in the filename.

I cant understand why but the sort order gets messed up, like in the attached screenshot.

[image: File Order]

Any ideas how I can get the output i need? A transformation of p is OK as long as it is easy to track back to the original value, and both p and id must be in the file name. I'm on Ubuntu 11.10.

Thanks a lot

Comment: My script and data is in R. Is the variables require transformation I would also do it in R

Comment: I agree this is an OS issue not an R issue.  Either put a number in the filename you want them sorted in, or get your OS to sort them in the order you want.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could try to make sure the p values are all the same length when converted to strings. Use sprintf:

```
pstring = sprintf("%010.8f",p)
```

will create a string with exactly 8 decimals, leading and trailing zeroes, and for values 0 to 1 will always be 10 characters long (zero, point, then eight decimals).

```
sprintf("%010.8f",runif(100))
```

should show you what it does.

Adjust the format according to your taste, simmer gently, serve.

Comment: This works for me in Ubuntu. Quite nice how sorting is done with whole numbers rather then per number.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
p <- gsub(".", "x", p)
png(paste(p," - ", id,".png)
```